# AS3 HitTestPoint stops working with Array object

Tags: actionscript-3

The Player falls through the ground `DisplayObject` after a few Frames. How can i stop him from doing it?

This function is called every frame with `ENTER_FRAME` in my mainloop of the game.

```
public function groundCollision() {
        for each(var moveG: DisplayObject in groundMoveArray) {
            if (moveG.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint.x, player.y + downBumpPoint.y, true)) {
                Bumping = true;
            } else {
                Bumping = false;
            }
        }
        if (Bumping == true) {
            if (ySpeed >= 0) {
                ySpeed = 0;
            }
            if (JumpPressed) {
                ySpeed = jumpConstant;
            }
        } else {
            ySpeed += gravityConstant;
        }
        ySpeed *= friction;
        playerY += ySpeed;
        player.y = playerY;
    }
```

Comment: I now realised.As soon as the second ground Module enters the stage, it stops working. But still don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for each(var moveG: DisplayObject in groundMoveArray) {
    if (moveG.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint.x, player.y + downBumpPoint.y, true)) {
        Bumping = true;
    } else {
        Bumping = false;
    }
}
```

Here you check player against all ground blocks in a loop. A player can intersect with only one block at once. So if it intersects with one block, it does not intersect with the other. But as you do the checking in a loop, your `Bumping` flag will be assigned a result from the last checked block. So if there are two blocks, and player intersects with the first block, your check will finish as `Bumping == false` because the last block checked is not the one that intersects with the player. So the player will fall down.

You need to add `break` statement after `Bumping = true` to exit the loop.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late response.